# Tensorflow 2.12 - Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8 in WSL2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, miniconda, cudnn

I have installed in **Windows 10** with **WSL2** (Ubuntu 22.04 Kernel), the **Tensorflow 2.12**, **Cuda Toolkit 11.8.0** and **cuDNN 8.6.0.163** in Miniconda environment (Python 3.9.16), normally and as the official tensorflow.org recommend. I should emphasize at this point that I want to use Tensorflow 2.12 because with the correspond Cuda Toolkit 11.8.0 it is compatible with Ada Lovelace GPUs (RTX4080 for my case).

When I go to train my model, it gives me the following error:

```
"Loaded cuDNN version 8600 Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libcuda.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
```

Is there any idea that is going wrong*?

The paths were configured as follows:

```
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
```

The files referring to my error were searched for using the following commands:

- `ldconfig -p | grep libcudnn_cnn` but it returned nothing so the file does not exist, and
- `ldconfig -p | grep libcuda` where returned `libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1`

Also, I have try to set the new environmental variable and include that to `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh` but without any luck:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/wsl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Note that when importing the Tensorflow, I get the following warnings:*

- `TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT`
- ```
  could not open file to read NUMA node:
      /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:1c:00.0/numa_node Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
  ```

In addition, an attempt to follow the [NVIDIA Documentation for WSL](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.8.0/wsl-user-guide/index.html), specific in section 3 -> Option 1, but this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ran into this problem and found a working solution after a lot of digging around.

First, the missing `libcuda.so` can be solved by the method proposed here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5663#issuecomment-1068499676

Essentially rebuilding the symbolic links in the CUDA lib directory:

```
> cd \Windows\System32\lxss\lib
> del libcuda.so
> del libcuda.so.1
> mklink libcuda.so libcuda.so.1.1
> mklink libcuda.so.1 libcuda.so.1.1
```

(this is done in an admin elevated Command Prompt shell)

Then when you run into the missing device problem (which you undoubtfully will), solve it by: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58681#issuecomment-1406967453

Which boils down to:

```
$ mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/nvvm/libdevice/
$ cp -p $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libdevice.10.bc $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/nvvm/libdevice/
$ export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib
```

And

```
$ conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc --yes
```

(verify by `ptxas --version`)

If you're running notebooks in VSCode remote WSL then you'd need to add `export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib` to `/$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh` (this is good practice anyway)

Comment: Your solution is comprehensive and sums up your painstaking search.  My problem has been solved, and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: after following this i had to re-install cuda again https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=es-419#windows-wsl2_1 I used version 11.8.0  even in this config steps https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html ,good news: now it works like a charm

Comment: I mean I had to hardcode this "newest" nvidia instructions to get version 11.8.0 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local

Answer (score 1):

I was able to depurate the fix for new version 11.8 , without reinstall everything

First same solution, i think this is breaking time to time, and you will have to re-check it:

```
> cd \Windows\System32\lxss\lib
> del libcuda.so
> del libcuda.so.1
> mklink libcuda.so libcuda.so.1.1
> mklink libcuda.so.1 libcuda.so.1.1
```

and then make the easy reinstall from this tensorflow link https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=es-419#windows-wsl2_1

which boils down to

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.8.0
python3 -m pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163 tensorflow==2.13.*
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDNN_PATH/lib:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
source $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
# Verify install:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

if you have to reinstall everything be careful in this step https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local
version is not 2.0 you have to hardcode commands to version 11.8

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local_11.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local_11.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

ref links: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=es-419#windows-wsl2_1
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just did the "rebuilding the symbolic links in the CUDA lib directory" part and it works for my case.
Should I go for part below?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34605963)